# Adding a non-nullable field on a production Django deployment

Tags: django, deployment, django-migrations

I have a production Django deployment (Django 1.11) with a PostgreSQL database.  I'd like to add a non-nullable field to one of my models:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    new_field = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

In order to deploy, I need to either update the code on the servers or run migrations first, but because this is a production deployment, requests can (and will) happen in between my updating the database and my updating the server.  If I update the server first, I will get an `OperationalError no such column`, so I clearly need to update the database first.

However, when I update the database first, I get the following error from requests made on the server before it is updated with the new code:

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: myapp_mymodel.new_field

On the surface, this makes no sense because the field has a default.  Digging into this further, it appears that defaults are provided by Django logic alone and not actually stored on the SQL level.  If the server doesn't have the updated code, it will not pass the column to SQL for the update, which SQL interprets as NULL.

Given this, how do I deploy this new non-nullable field to my application without my users getting any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Migrations should always be run at the beginning of deployments or else you get other problems.  The solution to this problem is to split the changes into two deployments.

In deployment 1, the field needs to be nullable (either a `NullBooleanField` or `null=True`).  You should make a migration for the code in this state and make sure the rest of your code will not crash if the value of the field is `None`.  This is necessary because requests can go to servers that do not yet have the new code; if those servers create instances of the model, they will create it with the field being null.

In deployment 2, you set the field to be not nullable, make a migration for this, and remove any extra code you wrote to handle cases where the value of the field is `None`.  If the field does not have a default, the migration you make for this second deployment will need to fill in values for objects that have `None` in this field.

The two deployments technique is needed to safely delete fields as well, although it looks a bit different.  For this, use the library [django-deprecate-fields](https://github.com/3YOURMIND/django-deprecate-fields).  In the first deployment, you deprecate the field in your models file and remove all references to it from your code.   Then, in deployment 2, you actually delete the field from the database.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by starting with a `NullBooleanField`:

1. Add `new_field = models.NullBooleanField(default=False)` to your model
2. Create schema migration 1 with makemigrations
3. Change model to have `new_field = models.BooleanField(default=False)`
4. Create schema migration 2 with makemigrations
5. Run schema migration 1
6. Update production code
7. Run Schema migration 2

If the old production code writes to the table between steps 5 and 6, a null value of `new_field` will be written. There will be a time between steps 6 and 7 where there can be null values for the BooleanField, and when the field is read, it will be null. If your code can handle this, you'll be ok, and then step 7 will convert all of those null values to False. If your new code can't handle these null values, you can perform these steps:

1. Add `new_field = models.NullBooleanField(default=False)` to your model
2. Create schema migration 1 with makemigrations
3. Run schema migration 1
4. Update production code
5. Change model to have `new_field = models.BooleanField(default=False)`
6. Create schema migration 2 with makemigrations
7. Run schema migration 2
8. Update production code

*note that these methods were only tested with Postgres.

Comment: I'd suggest combining step 4 and 6.  Django will force you to do this anyways as part of making a field non-null in a migration.

Answer (score -1):

Typically, a django upgrade process looks as follows:

LOCAL DEVELOPMENT ENV:

- Change your model locally
- Migrate the model (python manage.py makemigrations)
- Test your changes locally
- Commit & push your changes to (git) server

ON THE PRODUCTION SERVER:

- Set ENV paramaters
- Pull from your version control system  (git fetch --all; git reset --hard origin/master)
- update python dependencies  (eg pip install -r requirements.txt)
- migrate (manage.py migrate_schemas)
- update static files (python manage.py collectstatic)
- restart django server (depends on the server but could be something like 'python manage.py runserver')

Comment: Hi Davy.  I'm not asking about a general deployment process for a django project (what you described is already basically my deployment process).  I'm looking for a way to deploy this new boolean field that won't cause errors for my users.

Comment: You could put th site in maintenance mode: https://github.com/fabiocaccamo/django-maintenance-mode. But during server restart the users will still get an error msg

Comment: I've clarified the question.  I want an error free deployment